# inserting text before the output of a command line tool

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm using [uptime](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232243) and a few random `unxutils` tools to get uptime - the idea being that if it works here, I can use the same basic design for arbitrary information tools without needing to learn a 'grown up' scripting language. I *do* want it to be human readable so I want to crop out, and add in certain things.

What I need to do is, for example, insert `"the uptime for "` in front of the output for `uptime|cut -c 3-` so I get `"uptime for computername is 1 day<s>"` as an output.

Considering I'm already using two non standard tools, ideally, I'd like it to be using stuff that's native or in `unxutils`, but i can adjust as needed.

EDIT: using zsh is not an option - i need the output to work on the standard cmd shell.

Edit 2: I'm using windows, as per the tags. also, added a link to ms's implimentation of uptime. also corrected an error in my 'cut' command -

Comment: What bizarre hoops this question would have us jump through!  We can use the `cut` command from UnxUtils in our answers but not the `echo` command from _the very same package_?  That's quite arbitrary.

Comment: i didn't say that ;). i said no zsh, and that it didn't work with the window's native echo. I .. kind of didn't notice unxutils had echo

Comment: Well now you know.  (-:  And there are at least two ways to invoke it even though `echo` is built in to CMD.  Given that, and modulo the obvious changes of `;` to `&`, `barbaz`'s answer will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sed` and "replace" the start of the line with your prefix:

`uptime | cut -c 3- | sed "s|^|This will appear before regular output|"`

Comment: this works, almost - i had to use double quotes for it to work

Comment: Untested, unfortunately, since I'm not on Windows right now. But this is how it'd work elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Unxutils, but on unix you'd prepend your call with

```
echo -n "Hello World "; uptime
```

Since i don't use windows much and don't seem to have an `uptime` binary on my windows i can't really try your exact call, but in general the builtin 'echo' command coming with Unxutils `zsh` build seems to support the `-n` switch:

```
>UnxUtils\bin\sh
WINCOMP# echo -n "Hello "; echo World
Hello World
```

Comment: echo is the native windows echo, and just prints everything after that. the output for your command is "-n "Hello World "; uptime"

Comment: @Journeyman Geek: I just tried that out using the `sh` binary in the UnxUtils.zip and it works fine for me

Comment: i can't use zsh in this case, it dosen't seem to work with /exec on the irc client i'm trying to use the script with

Answer (score 0):

```
uptime|cut -c 2 | gawk '{printf("Uptime for computername is %d day<s>\n", $1)}'
```

Comment: i get "cut: write error : invalid arguement" - only when the gawk part of it is included.

Comment: It's OK i believe:

gjorgjit@eeepc:~$ uptime|cut -c 2 | gawk '{printf("Uptime for computername is %d day<s>\n", $1)}'
Uptime for computername is 1 day<s>
gjorgjit@eeepc:~$

Comment: Wait, wait. I do not use as you've written in the question "uptime|cut -c =2". I'm using "uptime|cut -c 2" instead. I'm on Linux. What about you?

Comment: windows. i'm using gawk, and cut from unxutils and the uptime tool from microsoft

Comment: Then, I suppose it should be: `uptime|cut -c =2 | gawk '{printf("Uptime for computername is %d day<s>\n", $1)}'`. Eventually `uptime|cut -c =2 | gawk '{printf("Uptime for computername is %d day<s>", $1)}'` if new line (\n) is causing troubles to windows.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Dj8da4AH - still not working -there's the error output.

Comment: Sorry, works in Lunux. I have no Win install at hand